# Is there a function that swaps two variables in a string?

Tags: c#

So we have to have code that swaps the integers in a two-digit number, such as "43" being "34". The user inputs a random two digit number and that number must be swapped.

I am not sure how to separate or mess with the two digit number that the user inputs into the console, so I have not had much luck in doing this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a two-digit integer");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(input);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: `.Reverse` if there's only ever two

Comment: `number = 10 * ( number % 10) + number / 10`

Comment: What have you tried yet? It seems like homework and you should do it/find a way yourself to improve imho.

Comment: This is my first class in c#, and I recently took a semester off from classes. I have been googling around and fiddling with the code for about 2.5 hours. I tried some math equations with remainder and didn't have luck there. I also tried to research on appending strings but I couldn't figure out how to grab the input number and recognizing that it had two integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Enter a No. to reverse");  
            int Number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  
            int Reverse = 0;  
            while(Number>0)  
            {  
                int remainder = Number % 10;  
                Reverse = (Reverse * 10) + remainder;  
                Number = Number / 10;  
            }  
            Console.WriteLine("Reverse No. is {0}",Reverse);  
            Console.ReadLine();
```

this will give you 34 if you entered 43.

You can checkout this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/reverse-a-number-and-string-in-c-sharp1 for more info.

Comment: Thanks I definitely will check it out, I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just reverse the string before you parse it:

```
string input = string.Concat(Console.ReadLine().Reverse());

// If the user entered "34", 'input' will equal "43"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try *modulo arithmetics*:

```
    number = number % 10 * 10 + number / 10;
```